# Gradle Build taking too long too complete

Tags: android, gradle

My gradle build is taking over 9 minutes to complete.

It was taking about less than a minute before which was ok. I dont know what went wrong.

I have tried a lot of adjustments and recommendations.

Gradle 4.4

my project level gradle is as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app gradle build file is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
    maxProcessCount 8
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.teamnifi.nifi"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.8'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.0"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    }
}

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my gradle project properties is as follows

```
   # Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide  /multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects

org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Offline work is selected in settings under gradle.
i have tried turning that off and syncing then turning it back on and building

The output off the latest build is as follows with offline work on in settings.

```
   Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources,     :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

 Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug,   src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use       registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\Josh\AndroidStudioProjects\NIFI\app\google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebugAndroidTest
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9m 44s
26 actionable tasks: 24 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

My gradle sync also takes over 15 minutes to complete.

All the while i have another project in android studio that runs normally and takes significantly less time to sync and build.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was a bunch of viruses and malware on my system. After running a boot time scan on my system i ran the build and now its back to taking a minute to run.